# How Convert this T-SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following SQL statement

```
    SELECT [CodeHouse]
          ,[CodeReq]
          ,[Address]
      FROM [ShahrdariProject].[dbo].[House]
      where [CodeReq] in
      (select [CodeReq] From [ShahrdariProject].[dbo].[HouseOwner] where [Name] = 'Alex' )
```

Can anyone please help me to convert this statement to LINQ?

Comment: No, but if you show what you've attempted so far, we can try to help fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL:

```
 SELECT [CodeHouse]
      ,[CodeReq]
      ,[Address]
  FROM [ShahrdariProject].[dbo].[House]
  where [CodeReq] in
  (select [CodeReq] From [ShahrdariProject].[dbo].[HouseOwner] 
   where [Name] = 'Alex' )
```

Is equivalent to this Linq:

```
var q = from h in db.Houses
        where db.HouseOwners.Any(x => x.Name == "Alex" && x.CodeReq == h.CodeReq)
        select h;
```

Comment: This Linq actually translates into an `EXISTS` clause in SQL, but it achieves the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var dbContext = new /**Your Linq DataContext class here**/())
{

    var results = dbContext.House.Join(
                dbContext.HouseOwner.Where(ho => ho.Name == "Alex"), 
                h => h.CodeReq, 
                ho => ho.CodeReq,
                (h, ho) => select new { h.CodeHouse, h.CodeReq, h.Address }).ToArray();
}
```

EDIT: Based on your query, I figured it would be oK to express the query using a JOIN instead of using IN

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> codeReq = new List<string>();
using(DemoDataContext db = new DemoDataContext()){
var houses = from h db.Houses where codeReq.Contains(h.codeReq) selec h;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code, i am sure this resolve your issue

```
var result = from house in db.Houses
    where db.HouseOwners.Any(z => z.Name == "Alex" && z.CodeReq == house.CodeReq)
    select house;
```

Enjoy......